# Best practice for a simple object literal: using "that" or the object's name?

Tags: javascript

Let's say there is a simple object literal which name will never change:

```
var car = {
    wheels : 4,
    construct : function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(that.wheels);
            console.log(car.wheels);
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

My question is: Which way is better? Referencing by the object's name or creating a new variable (which may take some time and memory and probbaly must be done in multiple functions)?

Comment: Better is subjective. Using `that` is more dynamic, and is the way I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the object, you should always refer to the object via `this` (or a copy of it, e.g. `that`, if required) to prevent the following breakage:

```
var car = ...

// do stuff

car = undefined;   // or anything else, perhaps by a code hacker in the JS console

// class is now broken
```

You should treat the variable name that happens to have been given to your object *on the outside* as unknown to you, and subject to change.

Someone else might call it something else, there might be multiple names, the name might suddenly point at some other object altogether.  Such variables are for the benefit of the "owners" of references to the object, and not for the object itself.

Comment: The problem is closures lose the "this" context. For example, I think setTimeout's function is always called with this = window.

Comment: @Random832 indeed, hence the `that` copy of the reference to `this`.

Comment: Ah. I think I misread you - it bears repeating, anyway, it can be surprising to people who don't know Javascript well.

Comment: We possibly overlapped - I was adding the stuff about `that` as you commented.

Comment: I see. An example would be using an interval. If I set `car = null` in another place the interval would still be able to run when using `this/that`, right?